# External displays suddenly stop working after booting

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, display, plasma, msi

So yesterday night I was still working on all my screens like I do every night. I switched off my laptop and unplugged all of the connected devices. In the morning I plugged in all of it like I do every morning. Accept this morning my two external display refused to come on and ive tried several things to try and fix them including switching off the laptop and unplugging everything and plugging back in when it on. It just tells me "no external display" in a little pop up box.

I am running Linux Ubuntu 18 with a KDE Plasma skin. Also this laptop dual boots to windows and while on windows everything works fine.

xrandr shows that it can not detect any additional displays apart from the laptops. -> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384

As for research I can not find any messages in dmesg but I found some in my syslog.

```
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(1920, 1080)
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs: 1
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Primary Output: false
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Change Screen Size: false
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Disable outputs: false
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Change outputs: false
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: #011Enable outputs: false
hpnote org.kde.KScreen[8465]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
```

Anybody else had this issue before?

Comment: I have the same problem. My system is dual boot to Windows too. I suppose the problem is with one of the updates that are applied on reboot.

Comment: Is there automatic updates on ubuntu now?
Next post will be how to disable that.
It's why i moved away from windows and shall do so from Ubuntu if that is the case.

Comment: Do you have an nvidia video card in your system?

Comment: Yes I do. RTX2060

Comment: Anything on this issue?